# What parts of speech are in 'assisting the Allies'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech

There is the sentence:

> In 1917, the United States entered the War assisting the Allies.

The problem is 'assisting the Allies.' What parts of speech are they? Are they a type of clause? Adjectival, adverbial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *In 1917, the United States entered the War* [*assisting the Allies*].

The bracketed element is a non-finite clause, more specifically a gerund-participial clause functioning as an adjunct (your adverbial) in clause structure.

Only words, not clauses, belong to a part of speech.

Comment: To read the phrase as the aside that it is, picture a comma: "The United States entered the War, assisting the Allies."